# IE and Firefox Overflow issue/bug?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to create a semi-responsive header for a website i am building, however i am running into an overflow issue with IE and Firefox. Chrome, however works perfectly.

I have created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t021jy9o/) to demonstrate what i mean.

In chrome, you should see something like this:

[image]

However in the same Jsfiddle on Firefox and Chrome, there is no red border on the bottom like this:

[image]

One way i tried to fix this was to change my css to this:

```
.header .header-image {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:0;
    bottom:1px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

This worked perfectly, BUT left a white space on Google Chrome (above the border and below the image)

What is causing this and how can I fix it and still get my desired effect?

Comment: Any comments on how i can better my question. Please don't downvote without explaining yourself. I would much rather improve the question. Thanks.

Comment: I see some stuff that maybe I don't understand why you take this approach, like positioning the image as absolute, is there a reason for this? It's because the overlay need to wrap the header? I try to fix it in your jsfiddle, and I get it to show the red border, but I did it floating the elements, so I don't know if that works for you, if it does, I'll create a new jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the red border, just change your header declaration for the .header to be like this one:

```
.header {
    min-width: 1100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:350px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

As you can see I've deleted the "display: table;" declaration and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you. I was using table to vertically center an overlay div, but i can just position it differently. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think it may have something to do with prefixes for Chrome and Firefox.
an example of a prefix is:
Android: -webkit-
Chrome: -webkit-
Firefox: -moz-
Internet Explorer: -ms-
iOS: -webkit-
Opera: -o-
Safari: -webkit-

Comment: i ment to put it in the comments sections sorry i wasnt sure on the answer